# Is there a way to know if a row is updated?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make an updated query like this:

```
"UPDATE users SET email_code='1' WHERE id=".$id." AND email_code='".$email_code."'";
```

and if the row is updated, then set `$_SESSION['verified']=1`

So I have to know if that row is updated.

Is there a way to know that ? Or I have to make first a SELECT query to know if that row exists ?

Comment: Do you need an observer, which fires some sort of event if any of the table rows was updated? Or do you just want to check whether the `UPDATE` was succesful? Or do you want to insert if no row exists to be updated?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `mysqli_affected_rows` to see if any rows were changed after you execute the query.

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0){
    // do session stuff
}
```

Comment: Or [rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) from PDO library, if that's his choice. )

Comment: In this way I have to use Mysqli class. Or not ?

Comment: You are free to user whichever class you want, if you're using `mysql_*` then you can use `mysql_affected_rows` if you want, but it's discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a trigger in MySQL on UPDATE for the users table and have MySQL run a script to set some variable which would access that session. But that'd be an unnecessarily huge pain in the rear.

I'd create an AJAX heartbeat on the page necessary to check and see if that row exists and then update the session that you need. Cleaner that way.

Answer (score 1):

Among the `mysql_` and `mysqli_` family of functions there is [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) and [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php). I'm not very familiar with PDO, but that must have something similar, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check if the query returned true or false and set $_SESSION['verified'] accordingly. [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php